# How to avoid System.StringException: No match found when only finding a substring and not a full match?

Tags: apex, error, regular-expressions

> **Preamble**
>
> I know (based on this question
>   ["No match found" when using Regex in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22696/no-match-found-when-using-regex-in-apex)),
>   that I can avoid "No Match Found" by wrapping the results in:
>
> ```
> if(pm.matches()){
>     //Code
> }
> ```
>
> However, this appears to be specific to when the Regex is a complete
>   match to the string.

---

> **Scenario**
>
> I am trying to find a substring within the string(s), a set of numbers
>   between parenthesis, like this (500). I want to return only the
>   numbers inside the parenthesis, to store this number in a Salesforce
>   number field.

I know I can use `pm.find()`, but it appears that if it **does not** find anything, it throws the "No Match Found" error instead of gracefully returning false, meaning I cannot do this:

```
if(pm.find()){
    // Code
}
```

The code above would still error when trying to do `pm.find` on a string with no results found.

> **ISSUE**
>
> I want to be able to put in any string and pull out the number **IF** one
>   exists, but with this "No Match Found" issue I can't throw a string at
>   it unless that string is guaranteed to have at least one set of
>   numbers inside a parenthesis. Any string that has no numbers will
>   throw the error. I considered putting this in a `try{}catch{}` block and just catching the errors gracefully, but this doesn't seem like the correct approach.
>
> How can I work around this to be able to check any
>   string but only set the number field in Salesforce in instances where
>   a result is found in the string?

---

I've included some execute anonymous code below that shows a success and a failure, for reference:

---

### **SUCCESS**

```
String str = 'Text Messaging Plan (500)';

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('.+\\((\\d+)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(str);

System.debug('Find? ' + pm.find());
System.debug('PM Group 1: ' + pm.group(1));
```

---

### **FAILURE**

```
String str = 'Text Messaging Plan (abc)';

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('.+\\((\\d+)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(str);

System.debug('Find? ' + pm.find()); // FAILS HERE
System.debug('PM Group 1: ' + pm.group(1));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misreading the logs: the error in your "failure" code comes from calling Matcher.group (because there was no match).

Try the following:

```
String str = 'Text Messaging Plan (abc)';

Pattern p = Pattern.compile('.+\\((\\d+)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(str);
Boolean found;

System.debug('Find? ' + (found = pm.find())); // (DOES NOT) FAIL HERE
if(found) {
    System.debug('PM Group 1: ' + pm.group(1));
}
```

Comment: thanks fox! I guess the wording of "StringException" had me thinking this was throwing an uncaught error